# App crashes in i0S 6, but not iOS 5

Tags: iphone, logging, crash, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

So I've been readying up on understanding crash logs and I believe I have my crash log symbolized, but I still don't understand it.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33c9a7f6 __sel_registerName
1   CoreFoundation                  0x359934ea ___forwarding___
2   CoreFoundation                  0x358eaf64 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
3   Texas42                         0x0012e132 -[HelloWorldLayer closeBidPicker] + 750
4   Texas42                         0x000e58f2 -[CCTimer update:] + 138
5   Texas42                         0x000e77e4 -[CCScheduler tick:] + 464
6   Texas42                         0x000f7e72 -[CCDirectorIOS drawScene] + 98
7   Texas42                         0x000f8ff0 -[CCDirectorDisplayLink mainLoop:] + 16
8   QuartzCore                      0x3360406c CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)
9   QuartzCore                      0x33603fc4 CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*)
10  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x32dbefd4 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc
11  IOKit                           0x392a9446 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3595b5d8 __CFMachPortPerform
13  CoreFoundation                  0x35966170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
14  CoreFoundation                  0x35966112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1
15  CoreFoundation                  0x35964f94 __CFRunLoopRun
16  CoreFoundation                  0x358d7eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
17  CoreFoundation                  0x358d7d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode
18  GraphicsServices                0x35e142e6 GSEventRunModal
19  UIKit                           0x36cb62fc UIApplicationMain
20  Texas42                         0x000bba82 main + 70
21  Texas42                         0x000bba34 start + 36
```

Based on what my users tell me, the app crashes when they call the "closebidpicker" method.  What exactly is this crash report telling me on this line?  I assumed the 750 referred to the line offset, but this method is not 750 lines long.  I am thoroughly confused.

I cannot reproduce this error on my phone or in the simulator.  It would be nice if I could at least pinpoint what line its on.

EDIT:

I'm calling closebidpicker using ccTouchEnded:

```
- (void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{  

    if (bidpicker.startPage==bidpicker.endPage && bidpicker.visible==YES && bidpicker.boo_pickermoved==NO && bidpicker.wasTouching==YES
        && bidpicker.isWindow==YES && bidpicker.wasWindow==YES)
    {
        [self schedule: @selector(closeBidPicker) interval:0.];
    }
}

- (void) closeBidPicker
//(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Entering CloseBidPicker");

    [self unscheduleAllSelectors]; 
    [self reorderChild:_label z:-1];

    int int_currentbid;
    bidpicker.bidpickeractive=false;
    bidpicker.visible=NO;
    bidPickerMenu.visible=NO;
    [self reorderChild:bidPickerMenu z:0];

    int int_pageindex;

    if(currentbid<=41){int_pageindex=45-currentbid;}
    if(currentbid>41){int_pageindex=1;}


    int_currentbid=currentbid;

    int int_currentpage;
    int int_bid;

    NSString *str;

    if ((int_player_counter==3 && currentbid>29)||int_player_counter!=3) 
    {
        int_currentbid=currentbid;
    }
    else 
    {  
        int_currentbid=currentbid+1;      
    }


    int int_pagevalues[int_pageindex];  
    int_currentpage=[[bidpicker valueForKey:@"currentPage"]intValue];

    if (30>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[30-int_currentbid]=30;}

    if (31>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[31-int_currentbid]=31;}

    if (32>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[32-int_currentbid]=32;}

    if (33>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[33-int_currentbid]=33;}

    if (34>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[34-int_currentbid]=34;}   

    if (35>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[35-int_currentbid]=35;}  

    if (36>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[36-int_currentbid]=36;}  

    if (37>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[37-int_currentbid]=37;}  

    if (38>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[38-int_currentbid]=38;}  

    if (39>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[39-int_currentbid]=39;}  

    if (40>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[40-int_currentbid]=40;}    

    if (41>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[41-int_currentbid]=41;}  

    if (42>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[42-int_currentbid]=42;}  

    if (42>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[43-int_currentbid]=84;}  

    else if (42*2>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[1]=42*2;}  

    else if (42*3>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[1]=42*3;}  

    else if (42*4>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[1]=42*4;}  

    else if (42*5>int_currentbid) {int_pagevalues[1]=42*5;}  

    if (currentbid<42)
    {
        if ((int_player_counter==3 && currentbid>29)||int_player_counter!=3) 
        {
            int_pagevalues[0]=0;
        }
        else
        {
            int_pagevalues[0]=30;
        }
        int_bid=int_pagevalues[int_currentpage];
    }

    else 
    {
        int_bid=int_currentpage*(int_currentbid+42);
    }

    if (int_bid<42 && int_bid>0)
    {
        int_currenthighbidder=1;
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d!",int_bid];
        [_player1actionlabel setString:str];
    }
    else if (int_bid==42){
        int_currenthighbidder=1;
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 Mark!"];
        [_player1actionlabel setString:str];    
    }
    else if (int_bid==42*2){
        int_currenthighbidder=1;
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2 Marks!"];
        [_player1actionlabel setString:str];    
    }
    else if (int_bid==42*3){
        int_currenthighbidder=1;
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3 Marks!"];
        NSLog(@"CloseBidPicker-14542");
        [_player1actionlabel setString:str];
    }
    else if (int_bid==42*4){
        int_currenthighbidder=1;
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"4 Marks!"];
        [_player1actionlabel setString:str];    
    }
    else if (int_bid==42*5){
        int_currenthighbidder=1;
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5 Marks!"];
        [_player1actionlabel setString:str];    
    }



    else if (int_bid==0)
    {
        str = @"Passes!";
        [_player1actionlabel setString:str];    
    }

    if (int_bid>currentbid)
    {

        int_player1bid=int_bid;
        currentbid=int_player1bid;
    }


//Code is failing when I call reorderChild, but only when computer bid 42 or more.
        [self reorderChild:_player1actionlabel z:1];
        [self reorderChild:_player1actionlabelbackground z:0];


    int_player_counter=int_player_counter+1;
    if (int_array_currentmove_player[int_player_counter]==2)
        [self schedule: @selector(player2Bid) interval:1.5];


    if (int_array_currentmove_player[int_player_counter]==3)

        [self schedule: @selector(player3Bid) interval:1.5];


    if (int_array_currentmove_player[int_player_counter]==4)
        [self schedule: @selector(player4Bid) interval:1.5];


    if (int_player_counter==4)
    {
        int_player_counter=0;
        [self schedule: @selector(determineBidWinner) interval:1];
    }
}
```

There really isn't anything special about the actual method and I don't see any reason why it would crash in iOS 6 and not 5.

What I don't understand is this...

It works fine in on my device if I build it directly for my device, but it crashes if I install the beta version through iTunes.

I was able to track down the code that was causing me issues.  When I comment out

```
[self reorderChild:_player1actionlabel z:2];
[self reorderChild:_player1actionlabelbackground z:1];
```

It works fine.  I have absolutely no idea why it is doing this.

Comment: Show us how you are calling and using `closeBidPicker`.

Comment: updated question to show additional code.

Comment: Any ideas?  Does libobjc.A.dylib imply its to do with the iPhone framework somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why/how, but moving

```
    [self reorderChild:_player1actionlabel z:1];
    [self reorderChild:_player1actionlabelbackground z:0];
```

To the top of my method solved the crash.